# Parsing JSON-encoded object on Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have problem read this `added_cards` on this JSON format

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "descriptor": 805336478,
         "start_time": 1487138400,
         "extra_type_info": 0,
         "added_cards": "{\"event\": [100355, 300347]}",
         "end_time": 1487224799,
         "event_name": "タイプセレクトガシャ"
      }, ...
   ]
}
```

I try to read the array content like this

```
JSONObject cards = resultObject.getJSONObject("added_cards");
tConventional.setText(cards.getString("event"));
```

But it showed error (Value {"event": [300351, 300353]} at added_cards of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)

So how to get the content of that array?

Comment: is `cards` a valid JSONObject? You should then use JSONArray if I am not mistaken, because `event ` is a JSON Array.

Comment: added_cards is your json string so you have to get it as String cards = resultObject.getString("added_cards");

Comment: May be above edit comment will help you ..

Comment: try like this JSONObject resultObject = result.getJSONObject(0);
   String added_cards = resultObject.getString("added_cards");  if you know that array contain single value ..if it is multiple than you have to take in loop

Comment: Check the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is a JSON array, to parse it do the following:

```
    JSONArray result = mainJSON.getJSONArray("result"); //mainJSON is ur complete JSON object
    for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){ 
       JSONObject resultObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
       String added_cards = resultObject.getString("added_cards"); 

       //Now, parsing this SubJSON
       JSONObject eventJSON = new JSONObject(added_cards); //I hope this line works
       JSONArray eventArray = eventJSON.getJSONArray("event");
       for(int j = 0; j<eventArray.length(); j++){ 
          JSONObject eventObject = eventArray.getJSONObject(j);
          tConventional.setText(eventObject.getString(String.valueOf(j)));
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Solved with your answer. But with a little bit change on eventObject. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Because **result** is `JSONArray` and also in **added_cards** `JSONObject`
>   ***event***  value is also `JSONArray`, it is not `String` type
>
> Try below code:

```
try {
        JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("result");
        if (resultArray != null) {
            int size = resultArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                JSONObject resultObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String cards = resultObject.optString("added_cards");
                if (!cards.equals("")) {
                    JSONObject addedCardsJson = new JSONObject(cards);
                    JSONArray eventArray = addedCardsJson.optJSONArray("event");
                    if (eventArray != null) {
                        int eventSize = eventArray.length();
                        ArrayList<Integer> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < eventSize; j++) {
                            eventsList.add(eventArray.optInt(j));
                        }
                        String eventsText= TextUtils.join(",", eventsList);
                        tConventional.setText(eventsText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```